# Scrum: Sprint Backlog: Who can see the Sprint Backlog and who are restricted to see the Sprint Backlog?

Tags: scrum, sprint, scrumboard

I am bit confused with a question, The customer can see the sprint goal, but should he be also able to see sprint backlog? or it is not allowed for the customer to see sprint backlog?

Comment: What do you mean by "customer"? Scrum doesn't define this term. The *Product Owner* must of course be able to see the backlog, because they own the backlog.

Comment: I completely agree and let me more specify the word customer, I mean stakeholders who have ordered the user story(direct customer with some requirements of product) and other scrum team who have dependency on our sprint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a programming question. See the warning on the [Scrum tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) "PROJECT MANAGEMENT QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Please ask these questions on ProjectManagement.SE"

Answer (score 2):

One of the Scrum Values is Openness. Scrum does not specify what a customer can and cannot see. However, you can apply the value of Openness as a litmus taste to a decision about what to share and what not to share.

Answer (score 0):

Customer can see the sprint goal, and Release goals. To me thats enough for a customer view. Sprint back log must be visible to the team, scrum master, product owner and other engineering stakeholders only. 
 Anyways its agile, as long as you give access to your backlog anyone can see the backlogs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great deal of value in making the sprint backlog visible to everyone.

Reasons for this include:

- Helps to set expectations on what will be done in the sprint
- Creates trust between those in the team and those outside of it
- Allows for feedback from stakeholders to the Product Owner
- It can protect the team from having additional work dropped on them - it shows that they are busy and what they are working on

Answer (score 0):

First of all of we talk purely Scrum book terminology, I don't think there is such party as Customer. Scrum defines three roles: Development team, Product Owner and Scrum Master. You can argue Product Owner represents customers but this is not really outlined in Scrum Bible.

Sprint backlog as an artifact is generally managed by the Dev team as this is essentially what's been committed to a sprint. So the only restriction I can think of in regards of Sprint backlog will be its modification. Changing it during sprint is only allowed if Dev team makes an agreement with the PO.